# How to uninstall openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme?

Tags: openstack

[image]

how to solve this error ?
generally when i install some new packages , i got the same error

Comment: Please, instead of the image, just paste the terminal output here using code markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type `sudo apt-get -f install`
Then, follow the command indications and whenever it finishes, try installing whatever you need.